# Starting FragmentActivity from Activity with Intent

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm getting a force close every time I try to start a FragmentActivity from an Activity using an Intent. Here's the code from the Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrgHome.class);
intent.putExtra("Username", organization_name.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

And here's the logcat:

```
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.project3.organizations.OrgHome
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.project3.organizations.MainActivity$1$1.mobDBResponse(MainActivity.java:76)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.mobdb.android.MobDBRequest.onPostExecute(MobDBRequest.java:78)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.mobdb.android.MobDBRequest.onPostExecute(MobDBRequest.java:1)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 16:52:45.823: E/AndroidRuntime(600):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 16:52:48.053: I/Process(600): Sending signal. PID: 600 SIG: 9
```

OrgHome.class is defined in the manifest correctly. What's going on here?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project3.organizations"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="OrgHome"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: how do you know that "OrgHome.class is defined in the manifest correctly"?

Comment: What is the `package` declaration at the top of `OrgHome.java`?

Comment: @Eric `package com.project3.organizations;`

Comment: any special reason you're using getApplicationContext()? if you're launching it from an Activity, it's probably better to use "this" (because Activity subclasses Context) and I've known weird stuff to happen when you use getAppCtx()

Comment: @mfrankli `this` and `GAC()` should do the same thing in this instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the manifest:

Use this if OrgHome is in the same place as MainActivity

```
<activity android:name=".OrgHome" />
```

Use this if it's in a sub-folder

```
<activity android:name=".sub.path.to.OrgHome" />
```

Or specify the whole path

```
<activity android:name="entire.path.to.OrgHome" />
```

Comment: I added the class using the WYSIWYG editor so I feel like it shouldn't err like this, but I'll add the `.` since it's in the same folder

Comment: the definition in the manifest isn't inherently wrong. it's just the combination of how you're defining it with how you're calling it, I believe. this answer is definitely the best way to fix it.

Comment: Did you change the file path at all?  The WYSIWYG editor doesn't do reference changes if you move them between packages.

Comment: @DeeV No I did not change the path. The files are both in the same package directory.

Answer (score 0):

for addressing the Fragment activities you should write (getactivity(),*nameofOtherActivity*.class); and you should be all right.